# INSERT & CREATE TABLE doesn't seem to be working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm currently experiencing some problems.

Basically, I use PDO and I want to create a table and insert some stuff into the table.

I've tried searching for solutions, but it doesn't seem like anything is working.

Please take a look at this:

```
public function install()
{
    global $con;

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE if not exists users
        (id INT(11) PRIMARY_KEY, 
         uname VARCHAR(30) , 
         pass VARCHAR (40))";

    $sq = $con->query($sql);

    if ($sq)
    {
        echo "Table successfully created!";
    }
    else
    {
        $this->errors[] = 'Error creating table: users';
    }

    $sql_code = "INSERT INTO users (
        `uname`, 
        `pass` ) VALUES( 
        `$this->username`,
        `$this->password`
        )";

    $sq1 = $con->query($sql_code);

    if ($sql_code)
    {
        echo "Successfull!";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "Error creating admin user!";
    }
}
```

NOTE: The database connection is set in another file called `config.php` and I've also included the `config.php` file to the code.

Comment: String __values__ should be in quotes (') not backticks (`): backticks are for escaping table and column names that might be MySQL reserved words

Comment: Have you considered using `$con->exec()` instead of `query()`?

Comment: Do you have permission to create the table? What does `errorInfo()` say?

Comment: Why would you use PDO and not use binding? :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there could be plenty of things going on, perhaps at the same time.

Maybe your database connection is failing (I'd recommend passing the connection `$con` by reference to the function `install` rather than using the [`global` keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)).

Maybe you don't have enough rights to create a table in the database.

Also you are not binding your parameters, this would be the correct way to do it:

```
$sql_code = "
    INSERT INTO users (
        uname,
        pass
    )
    VALUES (
        :userName,
        :password
    );
    ";

$sq1 = $con->prepare($sql_code);
$sq1->bindParam(':userName', $userName);
$sq1->bindParam(':password', $password);
$sq1->query($sql_code);
```

Comment: Thanks, everyone! And I figured out why it wouldn't create the table. It was because I had a syntax error in the SQL code. However, I'm having trouble with the binding now. 

Here's the error:

    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':userName, :password )'

`$sql_code = <<<EOSQL
    INSERT INTO users (
        uname,
        pass
    )
    VALUES (
        :userName,
        :password
    );
EOSQL;`